# Problem with Flow Direction in DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, spatial-analyst, flow-direction

I have the following problem with Flow Direction Tool in my DEM and with such wrong calculated flow direction in the centre of DEM I am unable to delineate any watershed. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is not a rendering problem?  What are the pixel values in the dark area?

Comment: Can you describe what we are looking at a little better and what you've already done to preprocess the DEM (Fill Sinks, Burn Streams)? My shot in the dark guess is we are looking at a water body and you may need to burn in stream lines to force flow direction to the water body's outflow point.

Comment: You can always add a tiny slope to the flat surface before performing the analysis, using exactly the same procedure employed to *remove* slopes: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11440.

Comment: If that raster that you're showing is a flow-direction raster than to me it looks like it's been derived using the D-infinity algorithm rather than the D8. The watershed tool is expecting a D8 flow pointer grid as input.