# Detrending DEM in floodplain?

Tags: dem, gis-principle

I am after the same solution to [Removing elevation trend over sloped surfaces?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11440)

I am following the steps outlined, but in the last step it states:

> In this expression [X'] refers to the the x-coordinate grid in the
>   original coordinates and [Y'] refers to the original y-coordinate
>   grid.

I'm not sure what is meant by the original coordinate grids. It doesn't look as if these are the original x and y values.

What are the coordinate grid values, and how I might obtain them?

That Q&A is quite old so perhaps there is a new method for carrying out this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to address this part of the question exactly, I followed Whited el al. (2007) https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/rra.1585 for the DEM detrending process. This gave me the desired results of removing the longitudinal gradient from the riverscape.