# QGIS - creating cross section to meet contour line

Tags: qgis-3, hec-ras

How can I automate the process of creating a shapefile containing cross-sections of a river centreline that will meet to a set distance given by a contour shapefile?

Is there a plugin or a set of functions that will allow me to set the cross-sections to start perpendicularly from a centreline, continue perpendicularly for a set number of meters, then bend till they snap to another shapefile (contours). Something like the pic below:

[image]

I use QGIS 3.6 and the final purpose is to automate as much as possible the creation of cross sections, refine what needs to be refine and then export them to HEC-RAS.

Comment: you can create cross-section if you have a DEM and profile tool plugin https://youtu.be/sIR3z2jC4L4?t=291

Comment: Not suitable for a 150 km long river. Also can't do it one by one.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look to this Q&A https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314361/find-higher-elevation-10m-perpendicular-point-from-stream-network-at-regular-i/314444#314444. It might be easier to set a kind of buffer from the stream based on high points and then work on defining the cross sections with the help of the centerline and the two edges of the buffer. Interesting task!