# Detrending DEM (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, dem, raster-calculator

I’m trying to detrend a DEM in QGIS. 
The best guidance that I could find on the internet was this question : [Removing elevation trend over sloped surfaces?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11440/removing-elevation-trend-over-sloped-surfaces)

I couldn’t understand that so I would like to know if someone could explain how to remove the tilt of a DEM. 
I know that the best approach is to fit a plane and then subtract this from the original DEM. But I can’t understand the criteria to create this plane and how I perform the subtraction.
I can use python if needed.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of detrending sufaces.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11440/removing-elevation-trend-over-sloped-surfaces/11463#11463

Comment: I use the method explained at 10.3 in this document: http://www.bajr.org/BAJRGuides/42_QGIS_StarterGuide/42_BAJR_Guide_QGIS.pdf

Comment: Commonly, you fit a first order polynomial to the surface then subtract it. I believe that there is a polynomial regression available in the SAGA module of QGIS but, it probably needs to be points and not a surface. You could convert the results of the point regression to  a raster then subtract the resulting polynomial fit. For a conceptual understanding is what is happening under the hood, Here is some code for doing this in R: https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco/blob/master/R/raster.deviation.R

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS:

1. Select several control points on your DEM to create the surface. Create a new point layer and digitize these points.
2. Obtain elevation data from the DEM at control points, by **Add raster values to points** tool in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector <> raster`
3. Start **Polynomial regression** tool in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Geostatistics`. Select your control points as the input, and choose **[0] simple planer surface**. Also make sure to set the extent and the cell size as same as your DEM.
4. Use raster calculator to subtract the output from the step 3 from your DEM. (or you may prefer **Raster difference** tool in `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Raster calculus`).

Answer (score 0):

I detrend a square DEM with sides of 2.5 km, resolution 1m like this:

1. Create a point grid with 10 m spacing
2. Sample raster values to give each point the value of the DEM
3. IDW Interpolate the sampled points to create a raster with 10 m resolution
4. Warp (resample) it to 1 m resolution
5. Raster calculate the difference between original DEM and the warp output:

Start DEM:
[image]

Detrended DEM:
[image]